# Using grep with delimiter and wildcard to search information from file

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I have the following information on text file.

```
abcde:fghi:aaaa
abdef:fgih:aaaa
fbcff:gggg:aaaa
```

Using ':' as a delimiter,I need to use grep to match searches for e.g fg*

output will be

```
abcde:fghi:aaaa
abdef:fgih:aaaa
```

In summary, I need to match searches using grep with wildcards inbetween the search term and delimter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
grep ':.*fg.*:' ./*
```

Answer (score 1):

With grep you don't need wildcard if searching for `:fg`. You can just use:

```
grep ':fg' file
abcde:fghi:aaaa
abdef:fgih:aaaa
```

Though if you want to search for pattern from `:fg` to `aa` then you can use:

```
grep ':fg.*aa' file
abcde:fghi:aaaa
abdef:fgih:aaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat test.data
abcde:fghi:aaaa
abdef:fgih:aaaa
fbcff:gggg:aaaa
fgcff:gggg:aaaa

$ grep -E '(^|:)fg' test.data
abcde:fghi:aaaa
abdef:fgih:aaaa
fgcff:gggg:aaaa
```